# Full-width element breaks a layout created with display: grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a simple layout that I've created with CSS grid consisting of a main element and a sidebar (please see snippet). Inside the sidebar, I have a child element that I would like to go full-width (i.e. ignore the padding around the layout container) on mobile devices.

The `.full-width` element does go full-width, but apparently what happens is it gets the whole grid to be `100vw`, which makes `main` and `aside` overflow `.container` (the grey element). How can I keep it full-width and keep `main` and `aside` within the boundaries of `.container`? Another requirement is that the full-width element remains in the flow of the document (so no fixed or absolute positioning).

```css
.page {
    background: pink; 
    padding: 30px; 
}

.container {
    display: grid; 
    grid-template-areas: "aside" "main"; 
    background: grey; 
    padding: 60px 0;
}

aside {
    background: yellow;
}

main {
    background: green; 
}

.full-width {
    width: 100vw; 
    margin-left: -30px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
<div class="container">
    <main>
        <p>I'm the main content</p>
    </main>
    <aside>
        <p>I'm the sidebar</p>
        <div class="full-width">
            <p>I'm the full width element</p>
        </div>
    </aside>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: whats you expected output. can you draw one image?

Comment: Please run the snippet at the bottom of the question and take a look: I expect the main content and sidebar (green and yellow elements) to NOT overflow the layout (grey element). The full width element should stay as it is, meaning it should overflow the layout and fit the page (pink element).

Comment: So the main content and sidebar should overflow right side until the pink background .

Comment: No, they should end where the grey element ends. Only the red element should overflow the grey element (like it already does).

Comment: Sorry, not understand clearly. draw the image as a output. otherwise I can't able to help you. Just a take a screenshot and edit upload a link in comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and easy solution is to set the columns to be `100%` to avoid the overflow:

```css
.page {
  background: pink;
  padding: 30px;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "aside" "main";
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  background: grey;
  padding: 60px 0;
}

aside {
  background: yellow;
}

main {
  background: green;
}

.full-width {
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: -30px;
  background: red;
}

body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="container">
    <main>
      <p>I'm the main content</p>
    </main>
    <aside>
      <p>I'm the sidebar</p>
      <div class="full-width">
        <p>I'm the full width element</p>
      </div>
    </aside>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or simply use negative margin on both sides to have the full width you want:

```css
.page {
  background: pink;
  padding: 30px;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "aside" "main";
  background: grey;
  padding: 60px 0;
}

aside {
  background: yellow;
}

main {
  background: green;
}

.full-width {
  margin-left: -30px;
  margin-right: -30px;
  background: red;
}
body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="container">
    <main>
      <p>I'm the main content</p>
    </main>
    <aside>
      <p>I'm the sidebar</p>
      <div class="full-width">
        <p>I'm the full width element</p>
      </div>
    </aside>
  </div>
</div>
```